# Why Django form choice field don't showing initial value from model as selected

Tags: python, django

Cant get model value to be represented as selected in form choice field.
In template I have edit option for my object, and I want to populate all current object values in form fields, but chose fields always will show model default values. Any knowledge how to fix this thought django functionality?

So what I have now: first my model:

```
class ClientPriceSelection(models.Model):
    A_B_choice = (
        (50.00, 50.00),
        (25.00, 25.00)
    )
    ...
    p_four = models.DecimalField(
        choices=A_B_choice, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2,
        default=50.00, verbose_name="...", help_text="(---)")
```

my view:

```
    addon = get_object_or_404(ClientPriceSelection, id=addon_id)
    # print(addon.p_four)
    form = ClientPriceListSelectionForm(
        request.POST or None,
        initial={
            'p_one': addon.p_one, 'p_two': addon.p_two,
            'p_three': addon.p_three, 'p_four': addon.p_four,
            'p_five': addon.p_five, 'p_seven': addon.p_seven,
            'p_eight': addon.p_eight, 'p_nine': addon.p_nine,
            'p_ten': addon.p_ten, 'p_eleven': addon.p_eleven,
            'internal_notes': addon.internal_notes,
        })
    context = {
        "form": form,
        'client': get_object_or_404(Client, id=addon.agreement.client.id),
    }
```

my form:

```
class ClientPriceListSelectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientPriceSelection
        fields = [
            'p_one', 'p_two', 'p_three', 'p_four', 'p_five',
            'p_seven', 'p_eight', 'p_nine', 'p_ten', 'p_eleven',
            'internal_notes',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'internal_notes': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={'class': 'vLargeTextField', 'cols': '40', 'rows': '10', 'maxlength': '500'}),
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `addon.p_four` in the view is different from the default value?

Comment: Also, are you sure that `addon.p_four` contains a valid choice? If it is not valid then the form falls back to the model default value.

Comment: Also, if `request.POST` contains a value for a field, then that value is used instead of `initial`

Comment: @Ralf - In this example I have two choices 25.00 and 50.00, if I change it for example from 50 to 25, in object view I see correct value, and calculations are OK, but if I want to edit this object, values for chose will be set to default, all others will be shown as in db, additionally if I print this field value I will get correct value.

Comment: @Ralf - P.S. Issue here is that initial value passed to form isn't setting option as selected 
`<select name="p_four" id="id_p_four">
  <option value="50.0">50,0</option>
  <option value="25.0">25,0</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figure this out, for anyone who is struggling to get option marked as select by setting initial values to form, use choice field display option

```
initial={'your_field': object.get_yourField_display}
```

in my case its:

```
'p_four': addon.get_p_four_display,
```